# Sinatra Padrino simple App does not run

Tags: sinatra, thin, webrick, padrino

I have written a few plain Sinatra apps using data mapper.

I wanted to try Padrino.

Went to padrinorb.com

On the front page there is

```
gem install padrino
padrino g project myapp -d datamapper -b
cd myapp
padrino g admin
padrino rake dm:migrate seed
padrino start
```

All those commands seemed to work smoothly. Then when I type padrino start, it runs webrick (Is that right?) but nothing works - all requests are treated as 404s. Padrino 0.10.6

I'm sure its something simple. I have data mapper working in other apps. I am on OS X 10.7, using ruby 1.9.2. Any ideas on what's wrong?

Bonus question - is there a discussion forum for padrino?

```
 Ref: 
 Snow-Pro:magnus tandersen$ padrino start
  => Padrino/0.10.6 has taken the stage development at http://0.0.0.0:3000
 [2012-06-08 11:16:02] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
 [2012-06-08 11:16:02] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
 [2012-06-08 11:16:02] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=39918 port=3000
  DEBUG -      GET (0.0241ms) / - 404 Not Found
 DEBUG -      GET (0.0136ms) /__sinatra__/404.png - 304 Not Modified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to go to

```
http://localhost:3000/admin
```

Comment: That did the trick. I had tried /login, no luck, but admin worked. I either missed that or its something you have to know.  Why not have a default home page...? Thanks.

Comment: different than other frameworks padrino doesn't make for you an home page.